# Calculate Gain of TS922

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain, loop-gain

Im trying to figure out the gain of this opamp inside a st board. Here is the schematic where this opamp is used.
[image]
As you can see, the closed loop opamp with feedback has a voltage divider on the negative input (-IN1) which is formed by a 4.7k and 100k resistor. On the other hand, the second negative input (-IN2) is closed loop with the output (OUT2). This **differential amplifier** has Vcc- at GND which means (correct me if im wrong) that the closed loop at -IN1 and -IN2 can be viewed seperately, right?
The Datasheet tells about **Voltage gain and phase vs. frequency** which is calculated using a 10k resistor. In my case it is a 100k resistor. How can i get the gain at a frequency of 192 kHz? [image] [image]

Comment: Not a differential amplifier. Amplifier 2 provides a VCC/2 ref of 1.35V. The other is a standard non-inverting amplifier with a closed loop gain out to 1MHz.

Comment: Do you mean the upper amplifier with "Amplifier 2"? How do you find out the gain of the amplifier below (e.g. Amplifier 1)?

Comment: Do you know the standard op-amp configurations?

Comment: no. It is used by microcontroller on a PCB

Answer (score 1):

My question from comments:

> Do you know the standard op-amp configurations?

Your reply from comments:

> no....

Since you are new to electronics, operational anplifiers (Op-amps) must be on your list for things to learn.

These versatile elements have two basic configurations:

1. Inverting where the output is an inverted and scaled version of the input.
2. Non-inverting where the output is a scaled in-phase version of the input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feYExy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gain for the inverting configuration is \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=\frac{-R_f}{R_i}\$

The gain for the non-inverting configuration is \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}=1+\frac{R_f}{R_i}\$

The TS922 in the OP is a dual op-amp containing two separate amplifiers. You should be able to understand that both are configured as non-inverting amplifiers.

The upper amplifier (2) is used to provide a low impedance \$VCC/2\$ midpoint bias voltage of 1.35 volts. It is used to bias the lower amplifier (1) for single supply operation, and perhaps to be distributed elsewhere as MREF.

The lower amplifier is a preamp for the ADC.

Use the formula to find the gain of the lower amplifier.

Then draw a horizontal line on Figure 10 as shown in red below.

Then draw a verticle line from the 192KHz mark up to where it crosses the horizontal line as shown in blue.

Where the two lines cross is the gain at 192KHz. If the blue line crosses the open loop gain curve before the red line, then the gain is determined by the open loop curve.

The gain that I drew is incorrect. You now have enough information to answer the question with the information in the OP.

[image]

Comment: My calculations show that $1 + \frac{R_f}{R_i}=1+100/4.7 = 22.27$. Hence, if i want to get the gain at e. g. 1kHt, that would be $20*log_{10}(22.27) = 26.95 dB$, right?

Answer (score 0):

This amplifier IC contains two opamps.Opamp2 is configured as a unity gain follower.

**For OPAMP:2**

The output of the voltage divider is connected to non inverting input of opamp.

The voltage at the OUT2 pin will be (2.7V/2).

FOR OPAMP:1

This is an inverting amplifier with level shifting. The voltage required for level shifting is applied to non inverting input of opamp 1.

You ADC is unipolar and the input signal coming to the ADC may be bipolar.In such cases we will shift the input signal going to ADC.

The gain of your amplifier is same as the gain of the inverting amplifier.

You can use gain bandwidth formula for calculating the required bandwidth.

[image]